# Price elasticity vs Discount Elasticity

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, elasticity

I have a case where I do not have many regular prices, but I have many discounts (different kind) which last a different number of days. Is there something like discount elasticity and how to adjust the number of items sold when the discount period can differ? Obviously, when the price is in the store for one month, the sale related to this price can be higher than for the price which appears one week.